# How to get AJAX script to post

Tags: ajax, velocity

I am trying to get this AJAX script to post, but it is doing nothing. I am trying to get it to work on my development pc (localhost). See the AJAX script below. The HTML/Velocity is also shown below.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("select.country").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "$core_v2_page.Url",
            data: { country : selectedCountry } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#response").html(data);
        });
    });
});
    </script>
```

And the HTML/Velocity is as follows:

```
    #set($countries = false)
#set($countries = $Ibby_v1_LocationData.GetAllCountries())
<form>
<div>
#if ($countries)
 <label>Country:</label>
                <select class="country">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    #foreach ($country in $countries)
                        <option value="$country.iso2">$country.country</option>
                    #end
                </select>
#else
#end
</div>
<div>   
#if ($core_v2_page.IsPost)
#set($country = false)
#set($country = $core_v2_page.GetFormValue('country'))
#if ($country)
#set($regions = $Ibby_v1_LocationData.GetRegionsInCountry($country))

        #if($country != 'Select')
        <label>Region:</label
        <select>
        #foreach($region in $regions)
            <option>$region</option>
        #end
        </select>
        #end
#end
#end
</div>
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is the error message? what did you try?

Comment: There is no error message. It just does nothing when I select a country from the select dropdown. @Patch